# Add new Column with the constant value as list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im creating list like

```
var transactionList = result.select(col("transaction_id")).distinct().collect().map(_(0)).toList
```

I want to insert "transactionList" into a Dataframe and latter explode it

I tried it like

```
df.withColumn("transactionList" , ArrayType(for (id <- transactionList) lit(id))
```

But it is not working

Comment: try `df.withColumn("transactionList", lit(transactionList.toArray))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also replace `.map(_(0))` with `.map(_.getString(0))`

```
result.select(col("transaction_id")).distinct().collect().map(.getString(0))
```

You can use `lit` to convert the `literal` value to `Column`

```
df.withColumn("transactionList", lit(transactionList))
```

If you have `transactionList = List("a", "b")`

This will add a new Column `transactionList` as array with value `(a, b)` in all row.

> ```
> /**
>    * Creates a [[Column]] of literal value.
>    *
>    * The passed in object is returned directly if it is already a [[Column]].
>    * If the object is a Scala Symbol, it is converted into a [[Column]] also.
>    * Otherwise, a new [[Column]] is created to represent the literal value.
>    *
>    * @group normal_funcs
>    * @since 1.3.0
>    */
> ```

Comment: I get this error "Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(26, 29)"